# How can I calculate min, max, average of continuous Flow in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow

The function `soundDbFlow` generate a double data continuous with Flow, I hope to get max, main and average value of these datas, how can I do ?

The Code A is written by me, I think it's not good.

**Code A**

```
   var countInfo = mutableStateOf(0)
    var currentInfo = mutableStateOf(2.0)
    var aveInfo=  mutableStateOf(5.0)
    var minInfo = mutableStateOf(0.0)
    var maxInfo = mutableStateOf(10.0)

    private var valuesCount = 0
    private var sum = 0.0

    private fun soundDbFlow(period: Long=100) = flow {
          while (true) {
             val data=(0..1000).random().toDouble()
             emit(data)
             delay(period)
          }
    }


    fun calCurrentAsynNew() {
        viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            iniInfo()
            soundDbFlow().collect {setInfo(it) }
        }
    }

    private fun iniInfo(){
        valuesCount = 0
        sum = 0.0

        aveInfo.value=0.0

        minInfo.value=0.0
        maxInfo.value=0.0
    }

    private fun setInfo(input: Double) {
        countInfo.value = countInfo.value + 1
        currentInfo.value = input
        if (input > maxInfo.value) maxInfo.value = input
        if (input < maxInfo.value) minInfo.value = input
        sum = sum + input
        valuesCount = valuesCount + 1
        aveInfo.value = sum / valuesCount
    }
```

Comment: This looks good to me. What do you not like in this code? The algorithm?

Comment: Thanks! Maybe there is a better way to get these results based Flow.

Comment: You could create an extension function on Flow which would be a stateful intermediate operation which makes this calculation. But that's basically the same as your code, just more reusable. No way to avoid mutation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a nice [`DoubleSummaryStatistics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/DoubleSummaryStatistics.html) class in Java Stream API. It looks almost like what you need, except lack of the field containing the latest processed value (`current`).

If you're targeting JVM, you can reuse it:

```kotlin
class Stats(val current: Double) : DoubleSummaryStatistics(1, current, current, current) {
    //Override to show newly added `current` field
    override fun toString() = String.format(
        "%s{current=%f, count=%d, sum=%f, min=%f, average=%f, max=%f}",
        javaClass.simpleName, current, count, sum, min, average, max)
}
```

(otherwise, just reimplement it in pure Kotlin, optionally tailoring API for your needs)

To use it with `Flow`:

```
suspend fun main() {
    soundDbFlow()
        .map { Stats(it) }
        .runningReduce { acc, value -> value.apply { combine(acc) } }
        .collect { println(it) }
}
```